# ¿Cómo obtener el objeto City para eliminarlo?

Tags: java, datatables, hibernate, objeto, delete

Estoy haciendo consulta de 'hibernate' y me encuentro con el problema de obtener el objeto de la tabla para poder hacer el 'delete'. Había pensado en esta consulta:

```
public static void EliminarCiudad(String nombre) {
    City ncity = null;
    List<City> nCiudades = new ArrayList();
    Session sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tr = sesion.beginTransaction();
    Query consulta;
    consulta = sesion.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM City where city=:nombre").setParameter("nombre", nombre);
    nCiudades = consulta.getResultList();
    for(int i=0;i<nCiudades.size();i++){
      int a=  nCiudades.get(i).getCityId();

        if(nombre.compareToIgnoreCase(nCiudades.get(i).getCity())==0){
            ncity= nCiudades.get(i);
        }
    }
    sesion.delete(ncity);
    tr.commit();
    sesion.close();
    String mensaje = "Ciudad eliminada correctamente";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
}
```

El problema es que 'nCiudades' solo tiene nombres de ciudades, no objetos:

Esta es la clase 'City':

```
public class City implements java.io.Serializable {

private Short cityId;
private Country country;
private String city;
private Date lastUpdate;

public City() {
}

public City(Country country, String city, Date lastUpdate) {
    this.country = country;
    this.city = city;
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
}

public Short getCityId() {
    return this.cityId;
}

public void setCityId(Short cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
}

public Country getCountry() {
    return this.country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public Date getLastUpdate() {
    return this.lastUpdate;
}

public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
}
```

}

xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 19-ene-2020 12:17:37 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class catalog="sakila" name="Clases.City" optimistic-lock="version" table="city">
    <id name="cityId" type="java.lang.Short">
      <column name="city_id"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="Clases.Country" fetch="select" name="country">
      <column name="country_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="city" type="string">
      <column length="50" name="city" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
      <column length="19" name="last_update" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tenes varias cosas ahi que te están complicando:

1) La clase `Citi` tiene que estar declarada como `@Entity` y agregada a la lista de entidades manejadas por Hibernate. (Tal vez ya lo tengas hecho en xml)

2) Una vez que es un `Entity` no necesitas hacer un query nativo, podes hacer un query del estilo `List<Citi> ciudades = session.createQuery("from City as c where c.city = :nombre").setParameter("nombre", nombre).list();`

3) El query ya está filtrando por las `City` que tienen `city` igual a `nombre` por lo tanto el `for` que vuelve a hacer la comparación es redundante, va a devolver los mismos resultados que el query. En todo caso el `compareToIgnoreCase` lo podes reemplazar en el query haciendo que ambos lados de la comparación sean `lowercase`.

4) Para eliminar todos los resultados con ese nombre podes recorrer la lista de resultados llamando el `delete` con los objetos:

```
for(City c : ciudades) {
  session.delete(c);
}
```

Comment: No veo el enitity en ningun sitio te pongo el xml